# How to reference two AggregateRoots in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I have two domain objects, a `Parent` and `Child`. A `Parent` can have zero or more children, and a `Child` can belong to zero or more parents (in case of divorced parents).

So thinking about this in the context of Domain Driven Design I'd say that both `Parent` and `Child` are an `AggregateRoot`. Because this is a many-to-many relationship.

Now I'm wondering how I should model this in code. I need to be able to access the parents from the `Child` class, but also all the children from the `Parent` class.

So I'm thinking about doing it like this:

```
public class Parent : AggregateRoot
{
    public string FamilyName {get;set;}
    public IList<Guid> ChildrenIds {get;set;}
}

public class Child : AggregateRoot
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public IList<Guid> ParentIds {get;set;}
}
```

Is it OK to have both classes reference each other via their `id`'s?

Or is there perhaps a better way to model this?

---

## Background info

Parents and their children can be registered in our application. Our system then keeps a log of events that that child goes through. Swimming, going to the museum etc.

For example;

- a mom and her only child are registered in our application.
- In the mean time events are logged to the child entity. Visited a museum, went swimming etc.
- Two months later Dad needs to be registered in our system as well (coparenting). Mom and Das obviously should have a reference to the same child entity.

I need to be able to work with the following use case:

- On all even weeks of the year Mom is responsible for the child.
- On all uneven weeks Dad is responsible.
- If something happends on an even week (Mom), then this event will be registered.
- If the application later on retrieves the Dad aggregate, then he should not only get a reference of the same child as Mom, but should also see all the events that happend the week before.

So therefor a Parent can have many Children, and a Child can hsve many Parents. My problem is that I'm not sure how to model this in DDD.

Comment: Based on your description, I'm not sure that either `Parent` or `Child` should be an AggregateRoot.  Have you considered abstracting both within another Aggregate (e.g. `Family`)?  What are the commands that are processed by Parents and Children?

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach I could create an Aggregate `Family`. Does that mean that both `Parent` and `Child` are not aggregates anymore when they fall within the `Family` Aggregate? Also I still need the flexibility to add the same `Child` to another `Parent`, which would then be from another `Family`. How should I model that?

Comment: If you create a `Family` aggregate, then Parent and Child would both be entities that belong to that aggregate.  As a general rule a type of entity can only belong to one Aggregate, but I don't see a problem with having the same instance of an entity have an association with two other entities of the same type.

Comment: Maybe I left out something important. I have a `Family` Aggregate. That has a `Parent` entity (Mom). Mom has one `Child` with some properties. Mom and are Dad are divorced. So Dad lives in another`Family`, thus is the `Parent` of that family. Dad also has one `Child`. This must be the same child as Moms. When the Mom Aggregate updates a property of her Child, then this should also be reflected to Dads `Child` entity. (Because we're talking about the same child). I don't see how this is possible in your example without giving `Child` its own AggregateID? Could you maybe elaborate on your idea?

Comment: You should definitely reference other Aggregate Roots by id. Please refer to  http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2020371&seqNum=4.

Comment: After reviewing your background info, it sounds like `Child` actually needs to the AggregateRoot, and that the `Parent` and `Family` are just entities associated with the `Child`.  Are there domain events that apply to the `Parent` or the `Family` independently of the `Child`?

Comment: @Vivendi DDD aggregates are here to transition your system to its following state while enforcing *invariants* and business rules. From your problem description, there doesn't seem to be any. Aren't you overthinking a part of your model that is really secondary? What are the crucial rules that would break your application if not enforced?

Answer (score 0):

When ever I have two models that reference each other I force myself to look for a missing part of my puzzle.

It sounds like your business doesn't care who is the parent of a child is, it cares who is responsible for a child at a given point in time. So its possible that looks like you are missing a 3rd domain model: `Guardian` (Im sure their is a better name for this) which removes the need for  Parent and Child entities to explicitly reference each other.

```
class Guardian {
    GuardianId Id {get;private set;}
    ParentId ParentId {get;private set;}
    ChildId ChildId {get;private set;}
    List<DateRule> WhenResponsible {get;private set;}

    bool IsResponsibleForChildAt(date day) {
      return WhenResponisble.Any(dr=>dr.AppliesToDate(day));
    }
}
```

Now depending on your business the `Guardian` model may more naturally fit inside the Child or Parent models, your domain experts should be able to help here.